# Connection Problems

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, help

I am having problems connecting to sites with Tor.  I made sure that all my firewall settings were properly allowing Tor and sure that my system clock was set to the proper time.  It was set to the correct time and time zone.  However after I checked my log in info I was shocked to see that the time read 17:10 when I connected (which is 5:10), but the actual time was 1:10 when I started Tor.

So my question is why does my Tor log info seem to be a whole five hours ahead of when it should be, and how can I properly fix to once again make it normal.

Can anyone please help me with my problem.

Comment: What is your OS? What is your TBB version?

Comment: I have a PC and I'm running tor 3.6.1

Comment: Is your computer plugged in?

Seriously, how did you install TBB? Also do you live in some restrictive censoring area? (e.g. China)

Comment: I just ran it normally. And no, I don't live in China, but I do uses bridges.